# Error in readonly text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this 2 button which is linked to the same modal form.

```
<a ng-click="addUser(user)" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addUser(user)">Add New User</button>
```

What i want is that if user click the first button, the user can enter their username, however if user click the second button their username cannot be change.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-readonly="readonly">
 <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
   <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
    </div>
```

i tried to set to readonly but it doesn't work that way. Anyone can help me?

```
 if (user) {
                $dialogScope.title = "Update User";
                $dialogScope.hideField = true;
                $dialogScope.readonly = true;
                var copy = angular.copy(user);
                $dialogScope.user = {
                    username: copy.username,
                    name: copy.name,
                    status: copy.status,
                    scope: copy.scope,
                };
            }
```

Comment: did you try ng-disabled attribute of input

Comment: ng-disabled="{your condition}"

Comment: you have applied ng-readonly to the div tag.. please try to apply on input.

Comment: @KaranPatel tried. but still not working

Comment: if you can make jsfiddle then i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-readonly=""` directive should work fine here. Set ng-readonly from a variable in your controller.

When you click button one set that var to true.
When you click button two set that var to false.

The `ng-readonly=""` flag must be used on an **input** field.

**Edit** - Plunker to demonstrate:

https://plnkr.co/edit/b5dYYT4HEYXE2Es9PUce?p=preview

Comment: i tried change ng-readonly in input field.still not working. but i am not sure what to change in controller. can u give me an example?

Comment: I'll put together a quick Plunker.

Comment: Here's an example https://plnkr.co/edit/b5dYYT4HEYXE2Es9PUce?p=preview if this helps you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Do the logic in the addUser function, pass in the value in as a second parameter. If that doesn't make sense create a Plunker demonstrating the issue.